# Planck-scale curvature in covariant LQG and quantization of length: does LQG apply also to the Planck-regime?

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-gravity, lattice-model, quantization, loop-quantum-gravity

In the covariant approach of loop quantum gravity (see [http://www.cpt.univ-mrs.fr/~rovelli/IntroductionLQG.pdf](http://www.cpt.univ-mrs.fr/%7Erovelli/IntroductionLQG.pdf) ), the theory is defined on a "lattice", similar to lattice QCD. In this case the "lattice" is the dual $2$-complex of a triangulation of spacetime. In the triangulation, the Riemannian $d$-dimensional manifold is approximated by gluing many **flat** $d$-simplices and curvature sits at the intersections on the $(d-2)$-simplices (hinges). This is standard Regge calculus to discretize GR. The difference with lattice QCD is that here the length of the segments of the triangulation is determined by the gravitational field itself, so it is not some external quantity (like the lattice spacing in QCD). The discretization approximates well the continuum theory when the curvature is small at the scale of the triangulation, such that the segments of the $d$-simplices are straight lines. So, if $L_s$ is the length of the segment $s$ of the triangulation and $R \sim 1/curvature$ is the curvature radius, we should require $L_s << R$. This is not a problem (in principle) in the classical theory.

Now we get to the quantum theory. Let us consider $3d$ Euclidean GR. LQG is defined on a discretization of spacetime with the dual of a triangulation. This is required to define the transition amplitude / path integral (then the theory is formally defined by taking the continuum limit). LQG ($3d$) predicts that length is quantized, $L_j \sim l_P \sqrt{j(j+1)}$, with $j = 0, 1/2, 1...$ In particular, there is a minimal non-vanishing length when $j = 1/2$, $L_{1/2} = L_{min}$ (which is of the order of the Planck length $l_P$).

The problem is the following: the triangulation on which the theory is defined requires that $L_s << R$, but if we consider a region with big planck-scale curvature, such that $R \sim 1/curvature \sim L_{min}$, there are **no** possible triangulations to start with where $L_s << L_{min}$, by definition. So if we trust the quantization of the length, it seems to me that this implies that when the curvature is planckian there are no possible consistent triangulations of the original manifold and the quantum theory defined on one such triangulation is therefore inconsistent. We should trust the results of LQG only when $R >> L_{min}$ (when one can find a consistent triangulation with $L_s << R$) and curvature is not too big, much below (I mean smaller than) the planck-scale curvature (therefore also the quantization of length is not that reliable at planck-scale in principle). But this is not what I expect from a theory of *quantum* gravity; on the contrary, this is precisely what I do not want from a theory of quantum gravity, since it should describe Planck-scale regime.

This is the question. Is there something wrong in what I've said and does LQG apply also to the Planck-scale regime?

** I used $3d$ LQG because there it is clear that length is quantized. In the physical $4d$ Lorentzian theory it is not clear to me (I am not an expert, but just a reader of the introductory book) if this is the case or not (there are papers about it). However, I think that the same argument applies, since in $(4d)$ LQG area and volume are quantized, so I expect this is also the case for the length. In any case, here the area is quantized as $A \sim l_P^2 \sqrt{j(j+1)}$, so there is a minimal non-vanishing area $A_{min} \sim l_P^2$ which in turn defines a minimal length-scale $L_{min} \sim \sqrt{A_{min}} \sim l_P$. Then the argument works in the same way as before.

Comment: Hey, I post this here rather as a comment and not an answer, since I am myself rather new to this topic. So feel free to discuss :-) Spin foam models (aka "covariant LQG", but I do not like this term, since spin foam models are nowadays an independent area of research) are background-independent appraoches to QG and as such, we do not use any geometry to define our theory. Gravity and continuous spacetime only should "emerge" in a phase or approximation of the theory.

Comment: So in other words, below the Planck scale, in all these background indepedent approaches to QG, like LQG, spin foam models, tensor models, GFT, etc, it doesn't make sense to talk about "curvature" below the Planck scale, since the  goal of all this approaches is to explain the very origin of this continuous and geometrical quantities. Hence, in your question above, this is not a problem, because you cannot talk about "high planck-scale curvature"...

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment :) Since you say that "spin foam modelS" are various approachES to QG, I will stick to use "covariant LQG" (or simply LQG) to indicate the specific approach presented in Rovelli's book to which I refer. Anyway, I think that what you say is not an answer to what I asked, for the following reasons. First, I understand that continuous spacetime should emerge from the continuum/classical limit, but to define the theory in the first place one should start from classical GR: discretization and then quantization. It is necessary a consistent triangulation to begin with.

Comment: Second, maybe I was slightly ambiguous in the choice of the words, since the curvature is the "inverse" of a length. When I say Planck-scale curvature $=k$, I mean $k \sim 1/l_P$; when I say curvature below the Planck-scale I mean **smaller** curvature, $k < 1/l_P$. The problem is not that I cannot talk about curvature higher than the Planck-scale, here $k > 1/l_P$. This is obvious in this approach. The problem is that the theory is inconsistent when curvature is around $k \leq 1/l_P$.

Comment: No problem :-) First of all, let me just mention that "spin foam models" is really a synonym of the older expression "covariant LQG". The latter term is only barely used in modern literature. And "spin foam models" is really A approach to QG. (The plural is only there, since there are several different models, like for 3d, 4d etc).

Comment: This is because the triangulation (from which we start!) cannot work here, it cannot approximate the continuum theory, and precisely because there is a minimal length. It is clearer working with the curvature radius $R\sim 1/k$. If we require $L_s << R$ for the triangulation to make sense, then if $R\sim l_P$ there are no possible triangulations, since $l_P \sim L_{min}$. This applies also if $R \sim \alpha L_{min}$, with $\alpha \sim 1-10$, of course. So we must assume at the beginning curvature smaller than Planck-curvature, so $R>> L_{min} \sim l_P$. This is not what we want.

Comment: Secondly, a really important point to note is that quantum gravity does not has to be the result of quantizing classical GR and in fact, in most approaches this is also not the case. As an example, the Euclidean 3d model from Rovelli's book you are mentioning is usually called "Ponzano-Regge Spin Foam Model". Now, originally, it was proposed by G. Ponzano and T. Regge without mentioning the relation to discretized GR.

Comment: The really just DEFINED the model via its amplitude (formula 5.48 in Rovelli's book) and said that is describing QG since the conjectured the asymptotic formula for the 6j symbols (5.52 in Rovelli's book), which was rigorously proven only much later by J. Roberts. The fact that you can "derive" this amplitude by discretizing classical (Palatini, triadic )GR (the approach taken in Rovelli's book) was observed much much later in the 90s. Although this is a nice result, this alone does not telling you that the model is a model for quantum gravity.

Comment: The model is really DEFINED via its amplitude and is a stand-alone theory, which is not necessarily the result of discretizing GR. In general, discretization is just a mathematical trick to make sense out of ill-defined expression like the path integral (compare to Lattice QCD), but it really important that discretization IS NOT THE SAME as quantiztaion. In fact, this are two totally different things (althoug often some kind of discretization is involved when quantizing a system, like to discrete spectrum of operators, etc). So to sum up: One should not think of QG as the result of

Comment: quantizing GR.

Last but not least, I meant "smaller and equivalent". The argument still stays the same. One should not think of things like geometry and curvature at the Planck scale, since this does not make sense. The goal of QG is exactly that all this objects appear in the dynamics of the theory. So talking about curvature at (or smaller) the Planck scale does not make sense at all, since this is exactly the reason why we need a theory of quantum gravity...

Comment: I hope this clarifies my arguments, if not feel free to comment :-)

Comment: Yes I think now I understand better your arguments, thanks :) Ok, from now on I will use "spin foam", no objections :D Anyway. The fact that there are approaches to quantum gravity which are not a direct result of quantizing classical GR is ok (like GFT), but it is not the case: in fact, it is a almost standard non-perturbative quantization of GR. I want to consider this theory and this procedure. In this view, in a sense, I do not care about the "Ponzano-Regge Spin Foam Model".

Comment: Indeed, as I understand, this model was derived postulating the discretization of length, it is more a guess, an Ansatz, rather than a theory. It fits better in the context of the spin foam theory discussed,  where it is derived from the quantization (not discretization!) 
of 3d GR.  Moreover, yes this is telling me that it is a model for quantum gravity (since is GR quantized, obviously provided all the consistency conditions etc.).

Comment: The fact that this model is defined as a stand-alone theory does not fit in the discussion about the quantization procedure which I'm discussing. For the discretization, yes of course is not the same as quantization, I do not see your point here. Here discretization is necessary to define the path integral, as in lattice QCD. My problem is: does the minimal length after quantization make inconsistent to define the triangulation in the first place? It would make impossible to take the continuum limit

Comment: (in a really broad sense, what would happen in lattice QCD if after quantization I cannot take the lattice spacing to zero?). In the spin foam model, after quantization I need to take the continuum limit: what does this limit mean if the corresponding triangulation from which we have started does not approximate any meaningful continuum  theory anymore?